# Spring Java Config Value as Field or Bean Parameter

Tags: java, spring

When using a Java Config with Spring is the best practice to wire values as a field:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Value("${property}")
    private String property;

    @Bean
    Foo foo() {
        return new Foo(property);
    }
}
```

Or as a bean parameter:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    Foo foo(@Value("${property}") property) {
        return new Foo(property);
    }
}
```

I believe its the latter but I don't see the specific recommendation in the Spring documentation.

Comment: We prefer @Value as fields for the configuration. I am not sure if there is a recommendation of one over the other

Comment: I think first approach is more useful when you use the same property for several beans just to eliminate mistake when you updated property name for one bean and forgot to do it for others.

Comment: In most cases, the preferred option is to use `ConfigurationProperties`. That said, field wiring is discouraged (though generally tolerated on configuration classes).